# Are $\omega(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$ asymptotically equal?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

> Is it true that 
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Omega(n)}{\omega(n)} = 1$$
>   where $\Omega$ counts the number of prime factors of $n$ and $\omega$ counts the number of *distinct* prime factors of $n$.

Is it true that $$\omega(n) \sim \Omega(n)$$

Where $$\omega(n)$$and$$\Omega(n)$$  are the prime omega functions

Comment: Hint: consider powers of $2$.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: The divisor function is bounded bt 2^\omega(n) and 2^\Omega(n). If they are asymptotically equal, then they are also asymptotically to the divisor function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not true. As [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551979/is-it-true-that-omegan-and-omegan-are-asymptotically-equal-to-one-anot/3551981#comment7304334_3551979) suggests, consider $n = 2^m$ for $m \ge 1$. You then get

$$\frac{\Omega(n)}{\omega(n)} = \frac{m}{1} = m \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As such, since $m$ can go to infinity, there's no upper bound on the fraction, so its limit can't be $1$. In fact, for primes, for example, the fraction is $1$, plus you can also get other larger values also depending on the value of $n$, so there's actually no limit of that fraction.